# Why is it wrong to use if here，in golang，remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array

Tags: for-loop, go, if-statement

1. I am a beginner and hope to get your help
2. it is remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array

   ```
   func remove(nums []int)int{
    i,j:= 0,0


    //Why is it wrong to use if here？
    // if j< len(nums)
    for j < len(nums){
        if i==0 || nums[i-1]!= nums[j]{
            nums[i] = nums[j]
            i++
            j++
        }else{
            j++
        }
    }
    return i
   ```

   }

   ```
     func main(){
        nums := []int{1,2,2,3,5,5}
        result := remove(nums)
        fmt.Println(result)
      }
   ```
3. please help me

Answer (score 0):

On short notice, here's what I have:

```
func remove(nums []int) int {
  temp := map[int]string{}
  for _, n := range nums {
    temp[n] = "exist"
  }
  result := []int{}
  for n, _ := range temp {
    result = append(result, n)
  }
  return result
}
```

And the output is:

```
[1 2 3 5]
```

Iterate through the slice and put into a map.
Iterate through the map and put into a slice.
Return the new slice.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sorted list of numbers, so you can store the last number added into the results list and skip adding into the result list if the next number is the same.

```
func remove(nums []int) []int {
    if len(nums) == 0 {
        return []int{}
    }

    result := []int{nums[0]}
    current := nums[0]
    for _, num := range nums {
        if current == num {
            continue
        }
        
        result = append(num)
        current = num
    }
    
    return result
}
```

If you are asking about why is it wrong to use `for j < len(nums)`, its not wrong, but using `for _, num := range nums` would make your life easier as you don't have to keep track of where you are in the array.

Comment: why can't use if j< len(nums)?

Comment: You are trying to loop over the list, `if` is for branching logic. Use `for` to loop.